# Member selection with overloaded dereferencing operator

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

If overloading the dereferencing operator (`operator*`), does the member selection operator (`operator->`) use the overloaded operator or does one need to overload it aswell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to overload the arrow operator separately.  More generally, even if there is a nice mapping between related operators in C++, if you overload one operator, you do not get the rest overloaded "for free" and must implement them yourself.

That said, it's easy to implement arrow in terms of dereference:

```
T* Class::operator -> () const {
    return &**this;
}
```

This works by dereferencing `this` to get a reference to the receiver object, then dereferencing that to invoke `operator *`, then taking the address of the returned reference to get a pointer to the object the arrow should be applied to.

You may want to look into the [Boost.Operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) library, which makes it possible to define many logically related operators automatically from a small set of base operations.

Hope ths helps!

Comment: so theres actually no "default implementation" of operator-> ?

Comment: @Paranaix- No, unfortunately not.  More generally, there are no default implementations of an overloaded operators (save the assignment operator) even if there is a reasonable way to implement that operator from other related operators.

Comment: And of course you can easily implement unary `operator*` in terms of `operator->`: `return *(this->operator->());`. C++ doesn't say which one you "should" implement in terms of the other, or bother to look at which one you've done and then provide a default for the other. Similarly with other operators there's more than one way to do it: implement binary `operator-` in terms of `operator-=`, or in terms of unary `operator-` and binary `operator+`? C++ doesn't tell you what the "base operations" are, and doesn't try to work out what you think they are. It's consistent, if not helpful.

Comment: If you do this a lot, it's also possible to define default implementations of some operators (like this) in terms of other operators (eg. in a CRTP mixin class) and have each class you want to use them inherit from it, but -> is sufficiently simple and rarely used it's probably not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

you can essentially implement a overloaded dereferencing operator but to then you have to deference it twice for your overloaded operator to come into play  !

Answer (score 0):

5.2.5 "If `E1` has the type “pointer to class `X`,” then the expression `E1->E2` is converted to the equivalent form `(*(E1)).E2`". The problem is that in your case, `E1` is **not** a pointer.